# Doesn't this create new ActorSystem everytime?

Tags: scala, akka

Confirming that every time you call Akka.system.actorOf or Akka.system.scheduler it'll create a new ActorSystem in the application? Looking at some code where it calls Akka.system.actorOf every time it has to create a new actor, which I think should have been context.actorOf to use the existing ActorSystem (which should have been created at the app startup). Is my understanding correct that calling Akka.system.actorOf every single time, to create a new actor, is very wrong?

Comment: in short, "no."  see @vladimir-matveev 's answer

Answer (score 3):

You create new `ActorSystem` *only* when you call `ActorSystem.apply` method:

```
val system = ActorSystem("YourApplication")
```

Of course, when you call methods on the system you *do not* create new systems, that is, the following:

```
val actor = system.actorOf(Props[SomeActor], "someActor")
```

won't create new system, it will just create new *top-level* actor in the `system`. You usually call `system.actorOf` method when you are outside of an actor, for example, in initialization code when there are no actors created yet.

`context`, on the other hand, is a way to interact with the system *from inside* an actor. `context` is a member of `Actor` trait, which is inherited into your actors. You use `context` to access actor system's scheduler, to watch actors, to create child actors, to change actor's behavior etc. `context.actorOf` will create *child* actor.

So no, calling `system.actorOf` for creating actors is absolutely *not wrong*. You just have to keep in mind that when you use `system.actorOf` you're creating top-level actors, and that's not something you need *always*. Usually you create one or several top-level actors, which then in turn create child actors and so on.

Comment: I understand system.actorOf never creates new actor system. My question was not that. It was if you literraly do this every time you want to create an actor "Akka.system.actorOf" then it'll create a new Actor system, no? Again doing this every time "Akka.system.actorOf" calling Akka.system everytime will create a new actor system, isn't that right? code I a looking at does exactly that, that it does "Akka.system.actorOf" every time while creating new actors, which should have ben system.actorOf (where system was created on application startup or something). Isn't this understanding correct?

Comment: @user2066049, what is `Akka.system`? There is no such thing in Akka library. Look like that you have some code which has its own `object Akka` which in turn has member `system` of type `ActorSystem`. Is that right? Then whether `Akka.system.actorOf` will create a new system or not depends on exact definition of `Akka.system`. If it is a `def system`, then it is possible that the system will be created anew for each call. If it is a `val system`, `lazy val system` or `var system`, then no, calling `Akka.system.actorOf` won't create new system.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs:

> Using the ActorSystem will create top-level actors, supervised by the
>   actor system’s provided guardian actor, while using an actor’s context
>   will create a child actor.

So basically, it depends on what you want to achieve.

More details [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html).

EDIT:

Concerning your concrete question (I am sorry, I misunderstood you), you should see an `ActorSystem` as a heavyweight structure that will allocate up to N threads, and each Actor will run within one of these threads (the key point here is that there is no mutable state). ActorSystems share common configuration, e.g. dispatchers, deployments, remote capabilities and addresses. They are also the entry point for creating or looking up actors.

Creating an `ActorSystem` is very expensive, so you want to avoid creating a new one each time you need it. Also your actors should run in the same `ActorSystem`, unless there is a good reason for them not to. The name of the `ActorSystem` is also part the the path to the actors that run in it.

There is no `Akka.system.actorOf` method in the current API. Normally you hold a reference to the application `ActorSystem` as others already showed you, and create child actors from that context:

```
val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("YourApplication");
val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[Actor1], "Actor1")
val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props[Actor2], "Actor2")
```

So, in short, I have never tried it but I assume every call to `akka.actor.ActorSystem` will try to create a new ActorSystem and it would probably fail if no different ActorSystem names/configurations are provided.

Comment: No, it does not depend on what the OP wants to achieve. The answer is "no": `actorOf(...)` does *not* instantiate a new `ActorSystem`.

Comment: My answer was more focused on whether it is wrong to create actors from ActorSystem or from context, which it IS pretty different.

Comment: Perhaps you should (or should have) made that more clear in your answer. To me, it now looks like you're answering the OP's question *"Confirming that every time you call Akka.system.actorOf or Akka.system.scheduler it'll create a new ActorSystem in the application? "* with an *"it depends"*.

Comment: I understand system.actorOf never creates new actor system. My question was not that. It was if you literraly do this every time you want to create an actor "Akka.system.actorOf" then it'll create a new Actor system, no? Again doing this every time "Akka.system.actorOf" calling Akka.system everytime will create a new actor system, isn't that right? code I a looking at does exactly that, that it does "Akka.system.actorOf" every time while creating new actors, which should have ben system.actorOf (where system was created on application startup or something). Isn't this understanding correct?

Comment: See updated answer. It would be of great help if you provide us of some code samples or a concrete use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one ActorSystem in a Cluster. thats why you cant use new.
Something very similar to main..

trying to learn by answering to it.